# Mkdocs code highlighting configuration, does not support jsx (React) code format，how to solve?

Tags: python, reactjs, blogs, mkdocs

My `mkdocs` setting is below :

```
theme:
    name: material
    highlightjs: true
    hljs_languages:
        - yaml
        - bash
        - javascript
```

hljs_languages are yaml, bash, javascript, but jsx format is not support, for instance :

```
let component = <span>{this.state.name}</span>;
```

When I use local markdown editor(Typora), it can highlight jsx code well
[image: local typora hishlight jsx format]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure why this doesn't work for me neither.
But it seems, that hljs struggles with JSX also:
https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/2998

Also it is be possible that Mkdocs uses an older hljs version that doen't support JSX already. I didn't find out which version Mkdocs uses.